# Understanding Function Overloading Ambiguity in C++: Square of Double vs. Float Argument

Tags: c++, function, overloading

Consider the following program, which is **based** on an example from the Deitel C How to program book.

```
// funOverloading.cpp

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// function square for int values
int square( int x )
{ 
   cout << "square of integer " << x << " is ";
   return x * x; 
}

// function square for float values
float square( float y ) 
{ 
   cout << "square of float " << y << " is ";
   return y * y; 
}

int main()
{
   cout << square( 7 ); // calls int version
   cout << endl;
   cout << square( 7.5 ); // calls float version
   cout << endl;
}
```

Because C++ by default treats 7.5 as a double and not float, hence since there is no float argument taking sqaure function, the program should result in a compiler error which should say something like

```
no overloaded function found for the function call 'square( 7.5 )' in 
cout << square( 7.5 ); // calls float version
```

But on [running](https://onlinegdb.com/5QNHfDp6c), I actually get the following error:

```
funOverloading.cpp: In function 'int main()':
funOverloading.cpp:24:18: error: call of overloaded 'square(double)' is ambiguous
   24 |    cout << square( 7.5 ); // calls float version
      |            ~~~~~~^~~~~~~
funOverloading.cpp:7:5: note: candidate: 'int square(int)'
    7 | int square( int x )
      |     ^~~~~~
funOverloading.cpp:14:7: note: candidate: 'float square(float)'
   14 | float square( float y )
      |       ^~~~~~
```

From this error it is apparent the compiler tries to call 'square( 7.5 )' but fails because of not being able to choose between the float and int version of sqaure. In fact if we didn't have the float square definition, the compiler will give no error and even warning at all. Check [here](https://onlinegdb.com/pbPgczrfn).

I have two questions, first why doesn't the compiler care 7.5 being a double and not raising an error on this and, even if compiler does try to call 'square( 7.5 )', why doesn't it simply choose the float version? I mean doubles are more like floats than ints.

Comment: Just for completeness: `square(7.5f)` would call the version that takes `float`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem arises because the literal `7.5` is a `double` and, as such, it can be converted to `float` OR `int` with equal priority.

You wouldn't have this problem if you add a `double` overload or if you are more specific with your literal, e.g. :

```
int main()
{
   cout << square( 7 ); // calls int version
   cout << endl;
   cout << square( 7.5F ); // calls float version
   cout << endl;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/1xncafn51

PS: Use better C++ books [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)